# Can´t open Amazon App from my app (amzn://apps/)

Tags: react-native

Can´t open amazon app in a React-Native app.
This is my code:

```
    let url = 'amzn://apps/android?';
    Linking.canOpenURL(url)
        .then((supported) => {
               if ( !supported ) {
                     console.log('No se puede manejar la url');
               } else {
                     return Linking.openURL(url);
               }
         })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err + ' | error '));
```

I tried the same code with Google maps and Gmail url reference to open that apps and works fine. So, i think it's the Amazon url wrong. I'm receiving supported = false.

Sorry for muy poor english.

Comment: What is the current behavior you're experiencing? You might have to add some Native permissions. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking. Also your code is hard to read when it's all indented the same.

Comment: Thx Scotty. I edited the post. This same code works fine whit Gmail url reference.

Comment: I think because Amazon accepts some params after this link, see https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android

Comment: Don´t works with params after link either